# Show that: $\overline{\int_{\gamma}g(\zeta)d\zeta} = -\int_\gamma\overline{g(\zeta)}\zeta^2d\zeta $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \gamma :[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ given for $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, and let $g:|\gamma| \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continues. Show that:

$\overline{\int_{\gamma}g(\zeta)d\zeta} = -\int_\gamma\overline{g(\zeta)}\zeta^2d\zeta $.

My proof:

Let $\gamma :[0,2 \pi] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$,  such as $t \longmapsto e^{it}$
And let $g: |\gamma| \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$  continues.

Let $\zeta = e^{it} $ y $d\zeta = ie^{it}dt$

$$\int_{\gamma}g(\zeta)d\zeta=\int_{0}^{2 \pi}
g(e^{it})ie^{it}dt$$

$$\overline{\int_{\gamma}g(\zeta)d\zeta} = \int_{\gamma} \overline{g(\zeta)} \cdot \overline{d\zeta} = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \overline{g(e^{it})} \cdot \overline{(ie^{it})}dt = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \overline{g(e^{it})} \cdot (-ie^{-it}) dt$$

$dt=\dfrac{d\zeta }{ie^{it}}$

Then,

$$-i\int_{\gamma}\overline{g(\zeta)} \cdot e^{-it} \cdot  \dfrac{d\zeta}{ie^{it}}= - \int \overline{g(\zeta)} e^{-2it}d\zeta = - \int \overline{g(\zeta)} (e^{it})^{-2}d\zeta=- \int \overline{g(\zeta)} \zeta^{-2}d\zeta$$

My problem is that $\zeta$ should be $\zeta^2$ no $\zeta^{-2}$. I don´t know where I am wrong. Thanks for he help in advance.

Comment: MathJax works in the title section, too, don't you know?

Comment: Thank you, and sorry @Shaun

Comment: It looks right to me, what book is this from?

Comment: Reinhold Remmert- Theory of Complex Functions. @IAmNoOne

Comment: You mind just telling us the page number...?

Comment: page 178, it's on chapter 6. section 2. Properties of complex path integrals. Exercise 2.